# Examples where $f(A\cap B)$ doesn't equal $f(A) \cap f(B)$

Tags: calculus, functions

What are some examples of maps where $f(A\cap B)$ doesn't equal $f(A) \cap f(B)$ where $A$ and $B$ are subsets of $\{1,2\}$. Would it be when the function is not injective?

Comment: $A=\{1\}$, $B=\{2\}$, $f(1)=1$, $f(2)=1$

Answer (score 2):

Let $A=\{1\}$ and $B=\{2\}$. Then $A\cap B$ is empty, so $f(A\cap B)$ is empty. But like you said, if $f$ isn't injective, we may have $f(1)=f(2)=1$, in which case $f(A)\cap f(B)=\{1\}$.

Comment: Yes, any non injective function provides an example: indeed, $f(A\cap B)=f(A)\cap f(B)$ for all subsets of the domain is equivalent to injectivity.

Comment: I don't understand how f(1)=f(2)=1

Comment: Are you just saying f(X)=1 ?

Comment: @Thomas $f$ is just some function that sends $1$ to $1$ and $2$ to $1$. It could be, say, a function on the natural numbers that sends each natural number to another. If $X$ is a subset of the natural number, then $f(X)$ denotes $\{f(x): x\in X\}$, or the set of natural numbers to which natural numbers in $X$ are mapped.